# Why do some linux binaries need to be recompiled?

Tags: linux, compilation, binary

I have always thought that linux binaries needed to be compiled on the local machine to be able to run, for different reasons (shared libs, ...).
But it seems that some are able to run across multiple linux distros without the need to recompile.

For example: hashcat. They built a 32-bit and a 64-bit binary, but both pre-compiled.

How is this possible, and in what situation, generally, is this possible ?

** I'm only talking about the Linux world.

Comment: Why do you think Lunux should be radically different from any other OS in this respect? (It isn't).

Comment: @n.m.: Because Linux has a strong Open-Source mentality, in which binary compatibility is not taken for granted but source code availability is. On Windows, it's pretty much the other way around.

Comment: @MSalters mentality is one thing vut technology is quite another. What technological differences are there?

Comment: @n.m.: The technological difference would be that the multiple distros are not related in the sense that different Windows releases are. Windows 8 is approximately a superset of Windows 7; Debian 8 is neither a subset nor a superset of any RedHat version. However, there's of course a large common subset.

Comment: @MSalters I'm able to run all major binary Linux packages on my distro, which is not even RedHat nor Debian derivative. Perhaps differences between distros are not that big.

Comment: @n.m.: That's because the packagers spent significant effort. I have already enough issues between Debian 7 and Debian 8, far more than I have between Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: @MSalters I doubt Microsoft or even Google would spend more than token effort on their Linux packages. They certainy won't go out their ways to satisfy fringe distro users. BTW I wonder what kind of differences you have encountered. Are they systemd related?

Comment: @n.m. : No, systemd doesn't directly impact us. It's a different install, but we didn't have an installer anyway. No, the problem is that we need to ship an altenative libc for Debian 7, and you can't statically link that. But Debian (and Linux in general) considers libc to be part of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to build binaries. One way is "static", which means that it includes all the required libraries in the executable itself, so there won't be external dependencies. However, when building you can decide yourself which libraries will be included and which will be looked for at run-time. So you can include some very specific libraries in the binary, but rely on some more standard libraries to already be on the system.

In addition to that, most libraries will provide a fixed interface that generally stays the same over time. That way it doesn't really matter which exact version you have on your system or how exactly it was compiled. As long as the functions the executable expects to be there, are there (and provide the same "behaviour"), things will run just fine.